# QT undefined reference error (Qextserialport)

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

i found this code for QT Creator and am brand new to the IDE, but have been trying to get this code to run. The main error I am seeing is about 12 instances of similar errors related to Qextserialport.

**C:\Users\Hassman\Downloads\aQtLow\aQtLow\dtransferusb.cpp:**

**34: error: undefined reference to `QextSerialPort::QextSerialPort(QextSerialPort::QueryMode, QObject*)'**

I'm not quite sure what to do about it, and am kind of lost. I am running QTCreator 5.1.1 and I imagine there may be a compatibility issue, but please someone give me a hand. Maybe I haven't linked the header to my file correctly? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
#include "dtransferusb.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include "C:/Users/Hassman/Downloads/aQtLow/aQtLow/qextserialport/src/qextserialport.h"
#include "C:/Users/Hassman/Downloads/aQtLow/aQtLow/qextserialport/src/qextserialport_p.h"
#include "globals.h"

dtransferusb::dtransferusb(QObject *parent) :
QThread(parent)
{


}

void dtransferusb::run()
{
   SerPort= new QextSerialPort();
    int ExpectedLength = NUMBER_OF_REGISTERS * 2 + NUMBER_OF_COILS / 8 + 1;
    QTime Startup, Sleeper;
    Startup.start();
    while(!Shutdown)
    {
        if(SerPort->isOpen())
        {//the port is open so check for data
            Sleeper.start();
            while((ExpectingResponse > 0) && (SerPort->bytesAvailable() < ExpectedLength))
            {
                msleep(25);
                if(Sleeper.elapsed() > 5000) break;
            }
                if(SerPort->bytesAvailable() >= ExpectedLength)
            {//data found
                Receive(ExpectedLength);
            }
            else
            {                  
                if((ExpectingResponse > 2) && (Startup.elapsed() > 15000))
            {
                qDebug() << "DTxfrUsb " << QString::number(Cfg.DTxfrUsb) << " finds the lack of expected response utterly demoralizing " << SerPort->portName() << " " << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
                P[Cfg.Prc].CommFailure();
                ExpectingResponse = 0;
                SerPort->close();
                Sleeper.start();
                while(Sleeper.elapsed() < 1000) msleep(100);
            }
            else
            {
                if(!WriteRequest())
                {
                    Send(1,0,0); //Function 1 siginfies "gimme data"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {//need to open the port
        SerPort->reset();
        SerPort->setPortName(Cfg.Port);
        SerPort->setBaudRate(BAUD9600);
        SerPort->setDataBits(DATA_8);
        SerPort->setStopBits(STOP_1);
        SerPort->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
        SerPort->setParity(PAR_NONE);
        SerPort->setTimeout(1000);
```

Comment: `QextSerialPort` isn't part of the Qt libraries, it's an external project. So you need to have built a `QextSerialPort` library and configured the project's `.pro` file or makefile to use the library. See the `QextSerialPort` docs for details such as: http://docs.qextserialport.googlecode.com/git/1.2/index.html  or https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I have looked at that page plenty of times and I don't know how to do this step. 2. Goto the top level directory ,run following command to generate library. how do i do the previous command?

        qmake
        sudo make install (or nmake install)

Comment: What toolchain are you using? Since you're on Windows you might be using either MinGW (in which case `make install` or `mingw32-make install`) or Visual Studio (in which case `nmake install`). It light be easiest to just include the `QextSerialPort` source into your project (Usage(1): Source code only).

Comment: Just for the record, I would suggest to use QtSerialPort these days. QextSerialPort is ancient, and pretty much abandoned. QtSerialPort was integrated into upstream Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QextSerialPort is a 3rd-party library that is not affiliated with the official Qt Project. You can find it at https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/ -- You will need to install QextSerialPort separately.

Some extra notes:

- Since you are new, I recommend using Qt 5.2.1 instead. It has many new features and bug fixes over Qt 5.1.1.
- "Qt Creator" is the name of the IDE, "Qt" is the name of the libraries. The current version of the IDE is Qt Creator 3.1, the current version of the libraries is Qt 5.2.1.
- Qt has its own built-in [QSerialPort](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qserialport.html) class, which I recommend if you want to write your own code.

Comment: THank you for the clarification JKSH. I have programmed with C and C++ in the past but this is quite new to me, and compatibility issues with different versions are really giving me a hard time. That being said, could you please help instruct me on how to install qextserialport separately?

Comment: The instructions are in the README file. By the way, where did you get your code from? Did you write it yourself, or did you download it from somewhere else?

Comment: I've read that readme plenty of times, and I can't seem to get it to work, i don't know what else i can tell you, it is quite frustrating on my end as well. I downloaded the code, didn't write it, but have been modifying it all day trying to get it to run

Comment: The README shows you 2 different ways to integrate QextSerialPort into your project ("How to use (1)" and "How to use (2)"). Which one you choose depends on the design of your downloaded code. Please edit your original post and paste the contents of the code's `.pro` file. Also, where did you download the code from?

Comment: Ok JKSH I got it to run again, I will be closing this topic, because I have a new error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

(1) To use these classes in your application, use the following include statement:

```
 #include <QtSerialPort/QtSerialPort>
```

(2) To link against the module, add this line to your qmake .pro file:

```
 QT += serialport
```

[Qt Serial Port Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html)